# In phpMyAdmin, constraints cause weird dropdowns when editing or inserting

Tags: mysql, constraints, phpmyadmin

I have added some constraints to some MySQL table fields. This seems to change phpMyAdmin a little bit, including constrained fields being presented as drop down boxes in edit or insert mode:

[image: Screenshot]

This looks a bit weird to me, as if phpMyAdmin wants to add titles but doesn't have the correct information. Am I correct in this assumption?

And why do the IDs go from 3 to 1, then back up to 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I needed to configure phpMyAdmin to display related records' titles/names.

http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000043.html

Now I see that the dropdown is ordering by name, then ordering by ID:

[image: Screenshot]